# Angular 2 Custom Pipe implementation

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-pipe

I've seen several examples of NG2 pipes in the web and recently started to implement one myself:

```
@Pipe({name: 'planDatePipe'})
export class PlanDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return localStorage.getItem(value);
  }
}
```

I was told in a code review that accessing localStorage is not a good practice here as pipe functions are generally 'pure'.  Is this considered bad coding for NG2?

Comment: Pipes are traditionally for formatting or mapping data.  They take a value in, modify it, and return that modified value.  I would also be against this practice.  localStorage should be treated as a service that is injectable for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible idea. A pipe shouldn't perform `get` functionality, but rather take a value, modify it and then return the modified value.

Complex logic in a pipe could drastically affect performance. Fetch the data you want in the component itself instead.

Comment: so they should be nothing more than "pure" functions is what you're saying.

Comment: I'm not sure what that term actually means, but I know that what you're doing right now is wrong :)